# Python: get driver value / calc driver expression

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

How to get driver value via python?

[image]

```
dr = bpy.data.objects["Cube"].animation_data.drivers[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Look at the value of the driven property.**

In the example given in question, the bevel modifier width of one cube is being driven by that of another. Have set up similar, the driver value being displayed via UI is 0.2

Given  the object of interest has context, retrieve this value by simply

```
>>> bm = C.object.modifiers['Bevel']
>>> bm.width
0.20000000298023224
```

Or from the driver, similarly to above a quick visual check confirms the driver is the zeroth

```
>>> for i, fc in enumerate(C.object.animation_data.drivers):
...     i, fc.data_path
...     
(0, 'modifiers["Bevel"].width')

>>> driver_fcurve = C.object.animation_data.drivers[0]
>>> dp = driver_fcurve.data_path
>>> dp
'modifiers["Bevel"].width'
```

And hence the value,

```
>>> C.object.path_resolve(dp)
0.20000000298023224
```

*If the value resolves to an iterable will require using the `array_index` of the driver [Look for link.]*

Consider investigating custom properties as input data to drive from.  For set up like above all drivers will break if the driver variable target object with the modifier is removed.

A custom property on the scene can be used as a global and on the object as a local (the `use_self` option is handy for this)

Comment: Note that this solution will work on render only if the user did not locked his interface